# Как правильно поставить ударение?

Tags: фонетика

Помогите решить,я сам немогу,ответ напишите на e-mail:nyrobcev2015@mail.ru.Спасибо.
Напишите куда ставить ударение в слове:позвоним

Answer (score 2):

Правильно будет позвонИм. И НЕ с глаголом пишется раздельно : "не могу"